# Zend_Auth::getInstance() not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am struggling from last 2 days with the following issue but still not able to resolve it.

With the help of http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/ I am doing an authentication module using `Zend_Auth` in Zend Framework. After successful authentication I am storing users data using `getStorage()`;

Example :

`AuthController.php`

In method `_process` I have written like this :

```
protected function _process($values) {
        // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials        
        $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
        $adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
        $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();             
        $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
            $auth->getStorage()->write($user);                            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`print_r($user)` showing the result :

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin [password] => cb3aefbdffbc81588f3d43c394428b16d4346b44 [salt] => ce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854 [role] => administrator [date_created] => 2012-12-29 11:04:40)
```

Also,

```
        print_r($auth->getStorage()->read());
```

This also displaying me the result.

Now, I want to display `Logout` link if user successfully logged in.

`view\helpers\LoggedInAs.php`

```
    class Zend_View_Helper_LoggedInAs extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function loggedInAs() {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $username = $auth->getIdentity()->username;
            $logoutUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller' => 'auth',
                'action' => 'logout'), null, true);
            return 'Welcome ' . $username . '. <a href="' . $logoutUrl . '">Logout</a>';
        }

        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();
        if ($controller == 'auth' && $action == 'index') {
            return '';
        }
        $loginUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'index'));
        return '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login</a>';
    }

}
```

But its not calling the method `hasIdentity` thats why its not going to the `if` block and

`print_r($auth)` showing output like this:

`Zend_Auth Object ( [_storage:protected] => )`

If I am doing `print_r($_SESSION);` then also it showing blank array. The issue is `$_SESSION` is working in controllers and modules but in `view/helpers` it displaying blank array.

`Bootstrap.php`

```
protected function _initSession() {
    try {
        Zend_Session::start();
    } catch (Zend_Session_Exception $e) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

I am using Zend Framework version `1.11`.

I am not sure this is the issue of `Session` or `Zend_Auth::getInstance()` or `view helpers`.

Because of this issue I am not able go forward for study `Zend_ACL` module. How can I fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put below code on top of your `view helper` class... `view\helpers\LoggedInAs.php`

```
/**
 * @see Zend_Session
 */
require_once 'Zend/Session.php';

/**
 * @see Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
 */
require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Abstract.php';
```

Comment: Your login and logout URL is pointing to different domains. I mean multi domains ?

Comment: Can you print `$this->_getSession();` and see what is coming ?

Comment: It showing the error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_View_Helper_LoggedInAs::_getSession() in D:\wamp\www\testproject\application\views\helpers\LoggedInAs.php on line 9`

Comment: For debugging, you manually add 'session_start()' on top of the helper file and see.

Comment: No, remove the line $this->_getSession() and try 'session_start()' on top

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21931/discussion-between-ultimate-and-sahal)

Comment: Set some session in controller and try to print from helper class. If that is also not working, there is somewhere session is unsetting in helper class. If the test session is working, your Zend_Auth is unsetting while login.

Comment: Problem is still persist...its not printing the session value in helper